# CoreData+CloudKit ... Skipping migration for 'ANSCKDATABASEMETADATA' because it already has a column named 'ZLASTFETCHDATE'

Tags: swift, core-data, watchkit, cloudkit, core-data-migration

Has anyone run into this error on WatchKit + CoreData + CloudKit?

> CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitMetadataModelMigrator calculateMigrationStepsWithConnection:error:](404): Skipping migration for 'ANSCKDATABASEMETADATA' because it already has a column named 'ZLASTFETCHDATE'

Note that the app works and I don't experience any problems with the app running in the simulator or on a real watch.  There are 9 of these 'errors'.

I'm thinking it has something to do with how persistent container is setup below.

```
description.setOption(true as NSObject, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey) 
...
container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true   // bring all iCloud changes into app
container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy // iCloud wins, local memory loses
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple this "skipping migration error" console output is normal/expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was because I was running my App on an iPhone simulator and I didn't register my AppleId in the simulator. Thats why iCloud didn't work (needs an account). After logging in, everything was fine.